# Why does formset.empty_form contain errors and forget initial values?

Tags: django, django-forms

`formset.empty_form` is great for generating a blank form that I can use in my JS. However, once the form has been posted, `empty_form` suddenly contains error messages and it magically forgets all its initial values. Why is that?

Instead, I have to do this stupid hack to get an *actually* empty form

```
empty_form = MyFormSet().empty_form
```

Regardless if there is post data. I can't even just overwrite it with

```
myformset.empty_form = MyFormSet().empty_form
```

Because it throws this stupid error message

> can't set attribute

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that, `formset.empty_form` intended to serve the extra empty forms required to be displayed as per the parameter `extra=n` passed to the formset, and doesn't serve your purpose to display as many empty forms in those places.

The new forms generated need to have an id similar and incremental to the one that would be in progression of the forms. Without the actual formset data and the count of the number of forms, how would `.empty_form` know the respective id.

Comment: Actually, my purpose is precisely what its intended for: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#empty-form It leaves `__prefix__` in place of the ID so that you can easily find-and-replace it with the appropriate ID.